# How can pandoc create an html segment

Tags: html, pandoc

Is there a way I can make pandoc generate an html segment, like just format it into a set of tags, and not be a complete html page? As in pandoc wouldn't include the `<body>` tag, just the contents that would be within the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the default behavior if you just use the `pandoc` command with no options.

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot, because I was playing with the discount package earlier and it generated the whole page.